# Android AdMob - NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzand()

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-api, admob

I'm getting crashes when trying to use the Firebase Admob Ads. I've followed the guide but I'm still getting this odd error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzand()Lcom/google/android/gms/common/zzc; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/zzc; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.zzc' appears in /data/data/tech.timmo.terminalwatch/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-basement-9.4.0_0d08c875bcfdb7f644dc6c5ac5fbcb017cb05b7c-classes.dex)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.zza.zzar(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzl.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzl.zzl(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzag.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at tech.timmo.terminalwatch.ConfigActivity$override.onCreate(ConfigActivity.java:77)
                                                                      at tech.timmo.terminalwatch.ConfigActivity$override.access$dispatch(ConfigActivity.java)
                                                                      at tech.timmo.terminalwatch.ConfigActivity.onCreate(ConfigActivity.java:0)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4111)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is my initialisation in `onCreate()` which the error points to the first line for `MobileAds.initialise`:

```
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));
AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice("9A3855EFE9914A3C40BF5A33DABB4701")
        .build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

The xml:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of error indicates to potential reason.

The device you're running the application might not have the support for the SDK elements you're using.

But in most of the cases, they are just random bugs that was introduced due to version upgrading of the `gms` library in the `build.gradle`.

Bring back the previous version of gms in your `build.gradle` dependencies and the error should be gone. Wait until the google releases the next version and then update the library dependencies with version upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Did you update SDK before this gone broken?

There is two `build.gradle` files, project one in `root\build.gradle` and module one in `root\app\build.gradle`. Open the project `build.gradle` file.

Go through all version numbers (buildToolsVersion, compile, ..) and update them according to the hints what Android Studio gives when you are hovering mouse cursor on them.

If do not fix with you, go `file->settings->'android SDK'->'SDK tools'` and update all tools.